# How to change the USB drive policy from "Quick removal" to "Better performance"?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, usb

I have a Seagate Expansion Drive with 4TB that I use in my dual boot system (OS: Ubuntu Impish Indri 21.10/Windows10Pro, both 64bits).

The speed of the driver was initially slow (speed transfers around 1-2MB/s, in 3.0 USB ports) in both OS.

For Windows, I found that was possible to change the working mode policy, from "Quick removal" to "Better performance". Done this, and the speed was increased to values around 90-120Mb/s.

I wonder now how can I do the same modification in my Ubuntu box.

Regards,

Camps

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1370494/edit) your question and add what version of Ubuntu you are using?  Thank you!

Comment: Is it still that slow (1-2MB/s, in 3.0 USB ports when running Ubuntu)? That's worse than a slow USB 2 pendrive. What file system is there now? exFAT or NTFS? If you want maximum speed with Ubuntu, I suggest that you use that ext4 file system, but then you will lose compatibility with Windows. - We don't know what you did to make it fast for Windows: change file system, change caching mode and/or something else?

Comment: @Terrance, I edited: it is Ubuntu Hirsute 21.10.

Comment: @sudodus It is formatted in NTFS as I need to read/write in Windows too. But this problem is just with that Seagate drive of 4TB, other drives (with lower capacity of 1TB-2TB) work as expected.

Comment: 21.10 is Impish Indri, recently released.

Comment: @sudodus, yep, I updated today, but the issue is old, since versions 20.04.

Comment: I suspect that there is some special setting in the drive itself, that makes it write more or less directly (and avoid caching) and that you can turn that off in Windows. It could be 'any' string, that should be sent to the drive to control it, and I think you must ask the manufacturer what it is and how to send it. I looked at the documentation, but it did not go into such details, only to select NTFS (which you have already). Please avoid advanced things with hdparm - it is known to brick USB drives.

Comment: Quick Removal = Windows does *not* caches disk writes. If you copy a bunch of files, anything that looks like is done *is* done.


Better Performance = Windows caches disk writes and updates the drive in the background.  If you copy a bunch of files, even though it looks like it got done, it's just sitting in cache waiting to write.  This is why (on Windows) you get super file copy speeds and are then stuck at 99% when you drag a bunch of files to a USB drive.


If Linux says a file copy is done, it's done.  It doesn't get stuck at 99% for 10 minutes, that's the other OS.

Comment: "It is formatted in NTFS" will make it slower than when it is ext2 or ext3.  "Better performance" is a commercial trick; it does not write quicker it just makes it write later (and hopefully before you yank it out of the port ;) )

Comment: btw: use the mount options `sync,dirsync` to enable thise.

Comment: @Rinzwind, The drive is very slow, 1-2MB/s, in 3.0 USB ports when running Ubuntu, slower than a slow USB 2 pendrive. Can you think of any reason for such slow write speed? And in that case, what could be done to fix it (except replacing the drive)?

Comment: Besides ntfs being slow as it is no not really and "Better performance" is probably not the answer. Maybe run a repair tool? chkdsk?